# Rails Defining an instance in controller by combining two conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to define the index of Projects in py projects_controller.

```
def index
  @projects = Project.where(user_id: current_user.id) #but also need to pull in Projects that have collaborators
end
```

Projects has_one 'User' as the organizer, but also has_many 'Collaborator' that belongs_to the Project.
I'm looking to have the @projects return a collection of any project that the user has either created or is a collaborator on.

Project Model:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :chat_room
  has_many :collaborators
 end
```

Collaborator Model

```
class Collaborator < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
end
```

I thought the solution would to be add an 'or' statement

```
@projects = Project.where(user_id: current_user.id) || Project.joins(:collaborators).where(collaborator: {email: current_user.email})
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your current solution is that you're using `||` instead of `+`.
`||` will likely always return `true` on the first condition in this case since the result, even if no records are returned, will be an array, which evaluates to `true`, even if it's an empty array.

If you want both conditions you should use `+`

`@projects = Project.where(user_id: current_user.id) + Project.joins(:collaborators).where(collaborator: {email: current_user.email})`

Answer (score 0):

This will give either user_id or email match results:

```
Project.joins(:collaborators).where("user_id = ? OR collaborators.email = ?", current_user.id, current_user.email)
```